# Anyone Else Experiencing "Internal Server Error" When Registering an Image?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is anyone else experiencing Internal Server Error when trying to register an image? I followed the instructions here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#create-an-image-share) and even tried on 2 apps but I get the same error.

I checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#register-an-upload as well, even if it only pertains to uploading videos.

Things I made sure:

```
- content type = application/json
- X-Restli-Protocol-Version - 2.0.0
```

Am I missing something? Is there a specific permission needed for it?

EDIT for more info:

URL:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload

Headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token_here>
X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{\"registerUploadRequest\":{\"recipes\":[\"urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image\"],\"owner\":\"urn: li:person:PERSONID\",\"serviceRelationships\":[{\"relationshipType\":\"OWNER\",\"identifier\":\"urn:li:userGeneratedContent\"}]}}
```

EDIT:

Finally was able to get past through the registration process. A sneaky space character was in my JSON body. I'm now able to register, upload the image, and do a share.

Comment: Try sharing your request url, headers, and body.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherOu  edited the post now.

Comment: I don't think these are the same but if it helps even having uploaded I'm having problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144091/problems-uploading-images-with-share-on-linkedin

Comment: Hey @Ukuser32, I checked your post and am wondering how were you able to get past the registerupload part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @Ervin Kalemi helped - it turns out the Asset wasn't yet available. Also - I think the mistake you're making is that you're sending the content type and linkedin header. For the actual CURL post the following worked for me (using PHP):

`exec('curl --upload-file '.$img.' --header "'.$this->oauth[0].'" \''.$url.'\'');`

`$img` is the file path and `$this->oauth[0]` is simply `Authorization: Bearer $token`. I *couldnt* however get the above working with PHP curl - I had to run it directly as above. So if there is a php-curl solution I would prefer to use that. But hopefully this will get you going.

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it to work and used your CURL code to move forward. I'm coding on C# but a quick CURL to C# converter did the trick. Thank you.